# How do I add an onclick to a div to display or hide data

Tags: javascript, fetch

Have seen similar questions but in my case am handling dynamic data from an API. Want when the user clicks the message with only **Subject** then the **body** shows and after the user can click again for
the body to hide. it works fine but want to add that functinality

````
    if(data.status == 200){

        data.data.forEach(message => {            
                msg +=  `
                <div id="read">
                    <p id="header">${message.subject}<span>......</span></span></p>
                    <p id="body">${message.message_details}</p>
                    <p>Sent on: ${message.created_on}</p>
                </div>
                <hr>`
                
        });
        document.getElementById("inbox").innerHTML = msg
        
    }```
````

Comment: where is div with inbox id?

Comment: it is in the main HTML the output is fine just want to add that functionality..

Comment: added the code in answer post.

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to add all of your dynamic blocks inside a wrapper `div` let's call it `articles` for example

after that, you need to add `eventListener` at this wrapper to listen for `click` event then check if the clicked element is the title toggle the `hide` class that is predefined in the `css` like this example below

```js
const wrapperEl = document.querySelector('#articles');

wrapperEl.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.id == 'header'){
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide')
    }

});
```

```css
.hide {
 display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="articles">
  <div>
    <p id="header">title 1<span>......</span></p>
    <p id="body" class="hide">article content here</p>
    <p>Sent on: 02/17/2020</p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <p id="header">title 2<span>......</span></p>
    <p id="body" class="hide">article content here</p>
    <p>Sent on: 02/17/2020</p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <p id="header">title 3<span>......</span></p>
    <p id="body" class="hide">article content here</p>
    <p>Sent on: 02/17/2020</p>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <p id="header">title 4<span>......</span></p>
    <p id="body" class="hide">article content here</p>
    <p>Sent on: 02/17/2020</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTE**: in this example, i just added some hardcoded blocks for testing but in your case, it will become from `API` in a dynamic way but in booth case, it should be inside a **wrapper** element

Answer (score 1):

Added the missing code to hide `body div`, and use `class="body"` instead of `id` for paragraph and div element, because these will be repeated.

```js
const data = [
{subject: "test123", message_details: "msg123", created_on: "12-05-2021"},
{subject: "test456", message_details: "msg456", created_on: "02-05-2020"},
{subject: "test789", message_details: "msg789", created_on: "11-07-2011"},
];

let msg = "";
data.forEach(message => {            
                msg +=  `
                <div class="read">
                    <p id="header">${message.subject}<span>......</span></span></p>
                    <p class="body">${message.message_details}</p>
                    <p>Sent on: ${message.created_on}</p>
                </div>
                <hr>`
                
});
document.getElementById("inbox").innerHTML = msg;

const bodyElements = document.querySelectorAll(".read");
bodyElements.forEach(function(bodyEle) {
  bodyEle.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    bodyEle.children[1].classList.toggle("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>My title</h1>
<div id="inbox">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how you could open the body again after hiding it?

Comment: updated the code to show and hide the body.

Comment: that is better but you should hide the body not title

Comment: modified the same.

Comment: The same issue its not working as I expected.. take an example of Gmail when u click in a message it shows all the details. this to is an emailing app practicing fetch data from Api

Comment: [link](https://github.com/FambaAbdulnassiirSiraji/html-css-projects/tree/gh-pages/fansmail) working on home.js

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use ids, because you will have the same id multiple times. So, you should make them class.

Let's say you use axios, or fetch API, doesn't matter actually:

```
axis.get('api-url').then(response => {
  // create your HTML outputs here
}).then(() => {
   document.querySelectorAll('.header').forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', toggleBody));
})

const toggleBody = (event) => {
  event.closest('.read').querySelector('.body').classList.toggle('is-open')
}
```